# ssrs reports working differently on server and Local

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I want users to see few reports which they have access, this is working fine when I open SSRS URL on the report server, but when I open the same URL in user local machine, the user can see all folders and reports from home button.

Suggest me if anyone of you got into the similar situation.

Thanks,
Ven

Answer (score 0):

While opening the URL in your client PC don't open it using the following URL
"http:*//servername:Port_number/reports*"
Because Reports shows the source folder and files.Instead of Reports you can use Reportserver i.e:"http:*//servername:Port_number/reportserver*"